# Orchard CMS Page Publishing destination and Integration with Asp.Net forms website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

```
I::  Orchard CMS  Page Publishing  destination
```

When we create / publish a page from Orchard CMS,

```
_contentManager.Create()
```

`_contentManager.Publish()`

where does the Page Content( HTMLs, Texts, Paragraphs etc...)  goes? The Sql CE is being used here and so far after browsing the tables in this database, seems the Page is going to this Sql CE database. To Which Table is the CONTENT of the page stored? Checking the tables, the PageIDs were found but content was found no where.

Or is the Page after being published going to File System? This doesn't seems the case.

```
II: Integration with Asp.Net forms website
```

There is an Asp.NET Forms website, which we need to migrate to Orchard CMS. Is this really possible ? The Integration of MVC and Asp.Net projects were done successfully for many projects ( None of them were on any CMS), now the need is to manage one  Asp.NET Forms website from Orchard CMS. Any pointers/Suggestions/Ideas on this ? Is it true that we can only manage MVC websites from Orchard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple places Orchard stores the data for a content item depending on what parts are attached, if the properties use infoset storage or record storage, or if the part is versioned.

It sounds like you are asking where the Body content of a basic page is stored. You can find that in the table Common_BodyPartRecord. The text column will be the html that is entered into the body of the page. The ContentItemRecord_id column is the id of the content item, the last entry would be the most recent version because the body part is versioned.

Other parts will be stored in the infoset of a content item. You can find these in the Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord, or Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord depending if what you are looking for is versioned or not. The data column has an xml value containing the stored values for a content item.

Comment: So like any page created within Orchard will go into Database only ? Since I checked that creating a page with any Extension say  '.aspx' is NOT possible.

Comment: Yes. Orchard does not use a file system to create pages, it stores everything in the database. Are you looking for a file that represents the page you created for editing?

Comment: Yeah. At the start I wasn't aware that it wasn't possible through Orchard to create pages with extensions. Such as when in ADMIN section, we create  a page, any kind of extension ( .html, .aspx )  in the Page URL is NOT allowed. But thanks for your Response and Time. Many things are much clearer after your guidance.